# Updating data in HABTM relation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two models *Firma* and *Znacka* in HABTM relation forming *FirmaZnacka*. I have a form with javascript autocomplete feature which looks like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input("Znacka.1.id");
echo $this->Form->input("Znacka.1.name");
echo $this->Form->input("Znacka.2.id");
echo $this->Form->input("Znacka.2.name");
```

When user submits the form, I need to save/update/create data to archieve:

- If the name of *Znacka* entered by user doesn't exists, create it (if it exists, don't create new!)
- Handle relations table record

Submitted data looks like this `$this->request->data`:

```
array(
    'Znacka' => array(
        0 => array(
          'id' => string '',
          'nazov' => string 'First'),
        1 => array(
          'id' => string '',
          'nazov' => string 'Second')
     )
)
```

The id of *Firma* is known, static and set by `$this->Firma->id = $id;` The code is running in FirmyController which has by default imported the Firma model. I'm not just using the form for creating new data, but also updating existing data.

I tried to find this out from The Cookbook with no result. I attempted to save it using `$this->Firma->saveAssociated($this->request->data)` and I also tried some other saving functions.

I know there is a brute force solution by looking on every Znacka's name and so, but I'm looking for some nice CakePHP solution without dozens lines of code.

I'm using CakePHP 2.0. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the association table named correcly? I think the first table name is supposed to be inflexed, not the second.

Comment: Oh sorry for my typo. I will edit it.